# Beta Chats endpoint in MS Graph giving UnknownError

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

API request: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/d90a45d2-0cec-45bc-a0a4-d1be70fc172d/chats

Microsoft Graph error message: UnknownError

Client request ID: 297f7c71-7eef-4d32-990d-f39267a79ffe

Timestamp: 2020-05-27T03:55:01

Response:

```
{
'error': {
'code': 'UnknownError',
'message': '',
'innerError': {
'request-id': '297f7c71-7eef-4d32-990d-f39267a79ffe',
'date': '2020-05-27T03:55:01'
}
}
}
```

Postman Request returning 403:
[image: Postman Request returning 403]

Answer (score 0):

You have to request Microsoft access to Protected APIs. Follow instructions here: [Protected API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20Teams%20APIs%20in%20Microsoft,channel%20messages%20using%20application%20permissions)

Note that some chat endpoints are not available in Application Context at all. Only delegated context works with those endpoints.